# R offset all the values in certain columns by one unit

Tags: r, offset

This is my dataset below. I am trying offset all the values in `Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4` by 1

```
ID      Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
314     3       4       4       3
820     1       3       1       2
223     1       1       3       1
915     1       3       4       4
542     1       2       3       4
521     4       1       3       4
978     4       2       4       2
260     3       3       1       2
892     1       4       1       2
```

The final dataset should looks like this below

```
ID      Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
314     2       3       3       2
820     0       2       0       1
223     0       0       2       0
915     0       2       3       3
542     0       1       2       3
521     3       0       2       3
978     3       1       3       1
260     2       2       0       1
892     0       3       0       1
```

I know a few ways to do this but I am worried they may not give me accurate results. Any suggestions on this is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arithmetic operations are vectorized.  We can directly subtract from 1 from the numeric columns and assign it back

```
df1[-1] <- df1[-1] - 1
```

-output

```
> df1
   ID Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1 314    2    3    3    2
2 820    0    2    0    1
3 223    0    0    2    0
4 915    0    2    3    3
5 542    0    1    2    3
6 521    3    0    2    3
7 978    3    1    3    1
8 260    2    2    0    1
9 892    0    3    0    1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(314L, 820L, 223L, 915L, 542L, 521L, 978L, 
260L, 892L), Col1 = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L), Col2 = c(4L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Col3 = c(4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 1L), Col4 = c(3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```